# Why making request in Django app (when Django project is deployed) leads to error "No data received"?

Tags: django, deployment

For example, I have created simple project:
[screenshot of project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNt5W.png)

utest_project/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^app1/', include('app1.urls')),
    url(r'^app2/', include('app2.urls')),
]
```

app1/views.py:

```
def index(request):
    r = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/app2")
    return HttpResponse('App1   ' + r.text + ' done!!!')
    # return HttpResponse('App1    done!!!')
```

app2/views.py:

```
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('App2')
```

I think this is enough to understand what project do. So, here is main question: if I use "manage.py runserver", everything is work, but when i try  this project with

```
uwsgi --http :8000 --module utest_project.wsg
```

I have in browser (http://192.168.1.252:8000/app1/):

```
No data received
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

But if comment

```
    r = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/app2")
    return HttpResponse('App1   ' + r.text + ' done!!!')
```

and uncomment

```
    # return HttpResponse('App1    done!!!')
```

everything is work fine with "uwsgi". So I think problem is in "requests.get", but I can not understand why. Can you help me?

Comment: Why do you want your site to make HTTP requests to itself?

Comment: I don't know is it good idea, but first app is api and second is site